# Key keeps getting replaced in dictionary C++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm trying to create a dictionary type of class for fun in C++, similar to the one seen in Python where you can designate a key and a value (which may be of any type in this case, including custom classes).

```
for (unsigned int x = 0; x < word.length(); x++) {
    if (!map.has_key(word[x])) {
        std::cout << "CREATING " << word[x] << std::endl;
        map[word[x]] = ics::ArraySet<char>();
        map[word[x]].insert(word[x]);
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < dist; y++) {
        std::cout << "HELLO!" << std::endl;
        if ((x + y) < word.length())
            std::cout << "ADDING " << word[x+y] << std::endl;
            map[word[x]].insert(word[(x + y)]);
        if ((x - y) >= 0)
            map[word[x]].insert(word[(x - y)]);
    }
}
```

The issue that occurs is that my key keeps being replaced. I'm trying to find letters that are within "x" range of the current letter I'm on. I append these nearby keys into a set, which is the value of my dictionary in this scenario.

For an example: **nearby(racecar,2)**

Should return a dictionary with values like this ...

dictionary('r' -> {r,a,c}, 'a' -> {r,c,e}, ...)

However, what happens is that the

```
if (!map.has_key(word[x]))
```

keeps failing and my keys keep being recreated each and every time along with the sets.

Comment: [MCVE] please as usual (and required)?

Answer (score 1):

Classic mistake of you believing your indentation implies a code structure that does not exist

```
    if ((x + y) < word.length())
        std::cout << "ADDING " << word[x+y] << std::endl;
        map[word[x]].insert(word[(x + y)]);
```

However, the statement `map[word[x]].insert(word[(x + y)]);` is unaffected by the `if`.

Add curly braces `{}` around the two statements here.

Comment: I did that one on purpose just to see if it would add the letters (and it did). It still doesn't fix the problem with the sets being reset to new ones.

Comment: So you haven't even to bothered to post code that is representative of your problem?   You'd rather people get distracted by problems you know are in the code that you don't care about?  Sheesh!  Refer the suggestion below your question about an MCVE.  Read the link carefully.

Comment: I actually posted nearly all the code that is within the function that's causing the problem. I've also noted where the problem occurred. Also, if I posted the entire code to the problem you still wouldn't be able to run it as it is connected to a bunch of other custom classes that are all interdependent. The only lines of code I'm missing are literally the parameters and the return statement to my code.

Comment: Clearly, you have not bothered to read the link, since you do not understand what an MCVE is.  It does not mean posting all your code.  It means YOU applying effort to provide the smallest possible sample of code that exhibits your actual problem, by removing code unrelated to the problem.   In the process of producing such a code sample, you might that an "Aha!" moment but, if you don't, other people have a fighting chance of helping you.   But it all starts with YOUR effort to isolate the problem, not - as you seem to expect - other people's effort to wade through your extraneous code.

Comment: I did read it; and having read your definition, I've posted as little of the code that should give a coherent enough picture for the problem. I would not consider any of it extraneous. In fact, any less code and people may be demanding for more to see the whole picture.